# DataAdapter insert function does not update database table

Tags: vb.net, tableadapter

I have a dataset called `Dataset1` which I have a three table adapters
when I try to use insertcourse function from the table adapter no
error shows up but nothing appear in the database table.
I read a lot of questions close to mine and did what they said but
with no luck.

I am working in VS2013 VB.NET code.

Hope someone could help me with this issue I am stuck in it for a week now.

This is the code I use:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim dt As New DataSet1.courseDataTable
    Dim da As New DataSet1TableAdapters.courseTableAdapter
    da.Fill(dt)
    da.InsertCourse("11", "11", 1, "11")
    da.Update(dt)        
End Sub
```

This is the connectionstring:

```
Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Database1.mdf;Integrated Security=True
```

Comment: I can load data from the course table into a gridview with no problem
using the getdata function from the same tableadpter

Comment: Your code doesn't really make sense.  You call `Fill`, which populates a `DataTable` all the records from the database table, then you insert a record directly to the database table, then you save the changes from the `DataTable` by calling `Update`, except that there are no changes to save.  I'll wager that the code is doing exactly what it should but you just don't know how to use table adapters or local data files.  That's OK, but let's first confirm that that's the case and then see that you learn how they work.

Comment: Firstly, that `Fill` call will return a number.  What is that number?  Get rid of the `Update` call.  Call `Clear` on the `DataTable` and then call `Fill` again.  What number does it return on the second call?  If the second number is 1 more than the first number then everything is working exactly as it should.

Comment: jmcilhinney  I added the fill and update methods to make the insertion work but after solving the problem as I mention below I removed the fill and the update methods and the code works like charm.

Thank you for your time :)

Answer (score -1):

I think I found a solution, just changed the connectionstring for the tableadapter
in mycase coursetableadpter to follow the actual physical path of the database.

old connectionstring: Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Database1.mdf;Integrated Security=True

new connectionstring: Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\mohammed\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\KCCSystem\KCCSystem\Database1.mdf;Integrated Security=True

for some reason there is two database files in the same project I don't know how that happened.

**Please: If any one could help us prevent or avoid this problem from the beginning please post in this question.**

Hope other people find it helpful.

Comment: You haven't solved the problem. As I suspected, you just don't know how local data files work. Read [this explanation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms246989.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). I strongly recommend using `Copy if newer` despite the warning there. I've never had issues and most rarely will.

Comment: Hi  jmcilhinney,

Comment: Hi  jmcilhinney, 
thank you for enlighten me to this issue I returned back the old connection string and as it is mentioned in the link you provided I changed the Copy to Output Directory property but whatever i choose a value to the property it keeps contacting the copy database file no changes happened in the original database file I opened it in server explorer to be sure and no new records there.
how to make the dataadapter  connect to the original database file??
another issue that there was no question when I make the database about making a copy there was no yes no message for that??

Comment: OK, you still don't know how to use local data files. You are correct that there are no changes made to the original and that is exactly how it is supposed to be. Why would you want your original database cluttered up with test data? You would then have to clean it before deploying. The whole point of the copy is that you can mess it up as much as you want while testing and still have a pristine original when it comes time to deploy for real. When you compile a Release build, the original is also copied to the Release output folder and you can deploy that copy without having to clean it.